# What is the scope of the snapshot of a StreamBuilder widget?

Tags: flutter, scope, stream

I have a page with a column of TextFields. If I populate the TextFields with an existing record I do it through a TextEditingController for each field. I was passing in the QueryDocumentSnapshot from another page but I don't want to do that any longer because I am adding functionality where that no longer works. I can't use StreamProvider because I need some variables that are not available at the top of the tree in order to create the StreamProvider.

I think the best place to create the stream is in the page itself.

So now, I want to get the snapshot and initialize the TextEditingControllers in a method within the class and use them in the "build" method.

I don't know what the scope is of the snapshot that I create using StreamBuilder. How do I access the snapshot in another method in the class?

This is the column code in the build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirestoreService().getSingleAgencyTrxns(widget.trxnId),
                builder: (context, trxnSnapshot) {
                  if (!trxnSnapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          autofocus: true,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          controller: clientFNameController,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            trxnProvider.changeclientFName(value);
                          },
                          decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                              hintText: 'Client First Name',
                              labelText: 'Client First Name'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          controller: clientLNameController,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            trxnProvider.changeclientLName(value);
                          },
                          decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                              hintText: 'Client Last Name',
                              labelText: 'Client Last Name'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }

    },

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
  }
```

I initialize the TextEditingControllers through a method call in the initState method:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    getTrxn();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is the getTrxn() method:

```
if (globals.currentTrxnId == null || globals.currentTrxnId == "") {
  // new record: Set the textFields to blank
  clientFNameController.text = "";
  clientLNameController.text = "";
} else {
  // Get the transaction
  clientLNameController.text = someProvider?.clientLName ?? "";
  clientTypeController.text = someProvider.clientType ?? "";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshot` variable is visible for every child widget, down from the `builder` property of the `StreamBuilder`.

This means that if you really need that info across your app you either:

1. Create a `StreamBuilder` on a top-ish level of your app;
2. Create several `StreamBuilder` across your app, which listen for the same events and behave accordingly.

The second option might be more complicated but I think that in some real-case scenarios it may be worth it: `StreamBuilder` re-builds its children when anything changes. Luckily, Flutter is smart enough to not re-build every element on the tree, but it still has to evaluate which Widget is marked as "dirty".

Comment: thank you for your response. In the last code snippet above how do I access the stream or DocumentSnapshot created in StreamBuilder? All of the code, including the StreamBuilder is in the same class so would I use Provider.of() to access the data? I'm new to this so I need the dumbed down version.

Comment: Hi there, no worries, thumbs up if it helped you. Once you're in the "builder" function block, you can access the arguments of that anonymous function (both `context` and `trxnSnapshot`), as long as you're inside the body of that function. Which means, in every child widget from there, down to the last one. `Provider.of()`, instead, access some data you've modeled trough `ChangeNotifier`, which I guess it's a different thing.

Comment: Your question makes me wonder: are you trying to manage *state* (if so, use the Provider package) or are you trying to manage a *stream* of data coming from somewhere else (if so, StreamBuilder is your go-to)? cheers!

Comment: All I am trying to do is access the data from the trxnSnapshot created in the "builder" function. I need to access it outside the "builder" function block but I don't know how to do that. I do have a ChangeNotifier class but I am not sure how to use it in this scenario. Should I use a StreamProvider and ChangeNotifierProvider instead? In which part of the class would I want to do this?